# Python YACC EOF reached immediately

Tags: python, yacc

Good evening,

I'm learning to work on lex/yacc using Ply (Python 3 / Win 8.1 system), but I've run into a snag: I can't seem to make yacc read the input file correctly.

If I hard-code the contents of the input file, I get the expected results, but if I try to read from it, yacc just reaches the end of file from State 0, stopping the syntactic analysis before it's really begun.

Here is my main (the tokens and syntactic rules are defined above - they don't seem to be the problem since the program runs fine when the input is hard-coded):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
lexer = lex.lex()
yacc.yacc()
inputfile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding="UTF-8")
lexer.input(inputfile.read())
for token in lexer: #for this part, the file is read correctly
    print("line %d : %s (%s) " % (token.lineno, token.type, token.value))

result = yacc.parse(inputfile.read(), debug=True)
print(result) #Stack immediately contains . $end and the p_error(p) I've defined confirms EOF was reached
tmp = "{{var1 := 'some text' ; var2 := 'some other text' ; var3 := ( 'text', 'text2') ; }}" #Same contents as the input file
result = yacc.parse(tmp, debug=True)
print(result) #correct results
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inputfile.read() reads up to the end of the file, so after it's successfully finished you know the file is at EOF.

You should only read() the contents of the file once:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    lexer = lex.lex()
    yacc.yacc()

    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as inputfile:
        contents = inputfile.read()
        lexer.input(contents)
        for token in lexer: #for this part, the file is read correctly
            print("line %d : %s (%s) " % (token.lineno, token.type, token.value))

        result = yacc.parse(contents, debug=True)
        print(result) #Stack immediatly contains . $end and the p_error(p) I've defined confirms EOF was reached
        tmp = "{{var1 := 'some text' ; var2 := 'some other text' ; var3 := ( 'text', 'text2') ; }}" #Same contents as the input file
        result = yacc.parse(tmp, debug=True)
        print(result) #correct results
```

Answer (score 2):

Using "with as" could also be a good idea, it is easier to read (imo) and is more 'robust':

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as inputfile:
    lexer.input(inputfile.read())
```

See : https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/